# Selenium - Getting "timed out after 60 seconds" error when using Exists method

Tags: c#, selenium, timeout, selenium-chromedriver, exists

I've been trying possible solutions that I can find online with the bottom error message with no luck.

```
An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:49357/session/8490ba8026d4a3d1bb60f08d2063ae79/elements timed out after 60 seconds.
```

---

---

```
    protected bool Exists(By by)
    {
        return wd.FindElements(@by).Any();
    }
```

When I run any of my scripts that come across the "Exists" method (posted above) where I'm expecting the element it's searching for to NOT BE there, I get the error message "The HTTP request...timed out after 60 seconds.".  However, this only happens when I run the test in Chrome and the element doesn't exist on the page (when it does exist, it has no issues with the Exists method).  When I run the script with Firefox, it has no issues at all.

I've tried extending my commandTimeout to twice the time, but it still fails at 60 seconds.  Tried changing the "webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(###))" to twice it's wait length, no success. Looked through everything in my code base that has a timeout method and tried to change those, no success there either.  I even went as far as change the ChromeOptions BinaryLocation to be pointed at the actual chromedriver.exe file.

If anyone can suggest on how to find the default location of the correct wait command or how to solve my issue with how to identify when an element isn't present on the screen, that would help immensely.

Comment: Are you familiar with `WebDriverWait` and/or `ExpectedConditions`? You can use [InvisibilityOfElementLocated](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_InvisibilityOfElementLocated.htm) to check when an element becomes invisible or is no longer present. Also, I assume this is `C#`?

Comment: @mrfreester yes, I'm doing this in C#.  And I didn't think to use either of those conditions.  I will look into those and give them a try.  Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Great, in case it helps, here is a line to use that. `new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds)).Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(by));` where `driver` is your `WebDriver`.

Comment: Was I was partially able to solve my problem, at least for the Firefox browser (chrome seems to be having the same issue still).  For the fix, I just had to extend the commandTimeout duration.